# Personalisation Rule matching later than expected

Tags: personalization

Strange issue with Personalization rules and Pattern Cards.
I have created a profile `TestProfile` with a single key `TestKey` (0..10).

There is a Profile card `TestCard` which allocates 10 to `TestKey`.
A pattern card `TestPattern` matches the value of 1 (tried any value up to 10) for `TestKey`.

Now I have a page `Test1` with `TestPattern` applied and I can see in “Explore Mode” that I collect the score for `TestKey`.

However, if I now visit a page `Test2` with the below personalization rule (basically I show a rendering only of `TestPattern` is matched in the visit), the rule only seems to be triggered after at least three visits of page `Test1` (the page with the profile card) on. This is despite the fact that I can see a sufficient score for `TestKey` after a single visit.

Even disabled all caching for a while but no joy :-(

Using Sitecore 9.1.1 and SXA 1.8.1

Any hints would be appreciated!

[image: Personalisation Rule Screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sitecore Personalization by default requires 3 interactions before Sitecore maps the contact's accumulated score to a pattern card.

This is why only after 3 visits, you see your rendering changes. You may however, change this behavior by updating the following setting.

```
<!--  ANALYTICS PATTERNS MINIMAL PROFILE SCORE COUNT
      Specifies the minimum number of content items with profile values that must be requested before Sitecore
      maps the contact's accumulated score to a pattern card.
      Default: 3
-->
<setting name="Analytics.Patterns.MinimalProfileScoreCount" value="3" />
```

If you change the value to 1, on the first visit it will set the Pattern Card of the user and when refresh a second time, the rendering will be updated.

Comment: Thanks, that was it, great stuff!